# How do I create different shaped buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create a restaurant floorplan for a booking system thing in tkinter and need to be able to click the individual tables, my thought is to have this as buttons. But of course there are rectangles, squares and circles, so how do i create the button, change the shape of the button, give the button text, and place the button where it needs to go.

I have tried to create buttons in various ways, all come out with an error or do not turn up at all. I am open to try anything at this point. Thanks

Comment: No actual Tkinter widget can have a shape other than a rectangle.  You'd have to fake your buttons as shapes drawn on a Canvas; the text would be a separate drawn item, and you'd need to add event bindings to get the shapes to respond to clicks.

Comment: If you want to explore a modern UI, then you need to throw out the awful hack that is tkinter and use a real UI framework, like Qt or wxPython.

Comment: A button is just a rectangle with a border that simulates a 3D look. You can do the same with rectangles or circles on a canvas. Or, you can create images with an image editor and use that instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts: tkinter isn't an awful hack. It's exceptionally useful for a wide variety of tasks. It just prioritizes functionality over form. Tkinter is a "real framework" just like Qt and wxPython. Plus, it's a fantastic toolkit for learning event-based programming due to its simplicity.

Comment: I think we've had this argument before...  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "traditional" button, you won't be able to do what you want to do. You can create "fake" buttons with the help of TKinter, as some people have suggested. I made a quick example with three shapes that print their names:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click(event):
    item = canvas.find_withtag("current")[0]

    
    if item == oval:
        print("Oval")
    elif item == square:
        print("Square")
    elif item == triangle:
        print("Triangle")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

#The oval (and other shapes) is created on the canvas and not yet a button

oval = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 90, 60, fill='blue') 

square = canvas.create_rectangle(110, 10, 190, 90, fill='red')

triangle = canvas.create_polygon(210, 10, 290, 10, 250, 90, fill='green')

#Here we make the shapes "buttons"
canvas.tag_bind(oval, '<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)
canvas.tag_bind(square, '<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)
canvas.tag_bind(triangle, '<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

At the end of the day, it acts like a button and looks like what you want.